# How to cross compile for ARM?

Tags: compiling, gcc, raspberrypi, arm

How do I set up GCC for cross compiling for the ARM processor? The host would be on x86_64 ( AMD64 - Ubuntu 12.04 ) and the target would be ARM (Raspberry Pi as well as Pandaboard - will do separate compilations for each)?

Answer (score 69):

Install `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` and `binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi` packages, and then just use `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` instead of `gcc` for compilation.

You need to be careful on what flavour of linux and  binutils you have on your target system.  The newest stuff is hardfloat, in this case you would do:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

This brings in the complete cross-compile environment, including binutils.

For using this GCC in the build process write:

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc make
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10 you get gcc-4.7 for 'gnueabi' and gcc-4.8 for 'gnueabihf'.

Comment: when I tried to compile I got `openssl/ossl_typ.h` not found error though I already installed `libssl-dev`.

Comment: If you get source code from `apt-get source`, after `apt-get build-dep` you can normally just compile with `dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc -us -r`
Is there a way to build a .deb this easily for ARM without changing the makefile?

Comment: @Maratyszcza could you please be more specific regarding the execution of line `and then just use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc instead of gcc for compilation`? When I compile I use a call to `make` which, AFAIK, naturally points to `/usr/lib/gcc` or something close to that. How could I call arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc directly?

Comment: @Momergil `CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc make ...`

Answer (score 18):

**64-bit ARM**

For 64-bit ARM, the toolchain prefix is `aarch64` and usage is:

```
sudo apt install gcc-9-aarch64-linux-gnu
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o main.out main.c
```

You can try it out on this C hello world with QEMU:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("hello");
}
```

and then:

```
sudo apt install qemu-user
qemu-aarch64 main.out
```

will output:

```
hello
```

Then a few fun things you can do to quickly see that ARM is actually running under the hood:

- GDB step debug it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590155/how-to-single-step-arm-assembly-in-gdb-on-qemu/51310791#51310791
- log the executed ARM instructions with: `qemu-aarch64 -d in_asm,out_asm main.out` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005303/how-does-native-android-code-written-for-arm-run-on-x86/44505097#44505097

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10.

**For reliability in serious applications, the disk image provider must also provide a compatible cross compiler**

Although you can install a cross compiler with `apt` conveniently, I must warn you that this is not necessarily reliable unless explicitly supported by the image provider.

If you pick the cross compiler wrongly, the following may happen:

- the dynamic linker is at the wrong path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929092/trying-to-run-a-cross-compiled-executable-on-target-device-fails-with-no-such-f/49993116#49993116
- binary incompatibility with the glibc and any other libraries you link against: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107263/how-compatible-are-different-versions-of-glibc

**Raspberry PI cross compilation**

For RPI in particular, the provided cross compilers are available at: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools and can be used as explained at: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64273/installing-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/83215#83215

```
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools
export PATH="$(pwd)/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin:${PATH}"
printf '#include <stdio.h>\nint main() { puts("hello world"); }\n' > hello_world.c
printf '#include <iostream>\nint main() { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }\n' > hello_world.cpp
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -std=c99 -o hello_world_c hello_world.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=c++11 -o hello_world_cpp hello_world.cpp
```

**Ubuntu cross compilation**

If you want to cross compile for Ubuntu arm64, I have never been able to find a clear reference on which cross compilers support which distro version: [What are the officially supported cross compilers for Ubuntu server alternative architectures like ARM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046294/what-are-the-officially-supported-cross-compilers-for-ubuntu-server-alternative)

**Buildroot**

My favorite alternative is to build your own image with Buildroot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557262/how-to-download-the-torvalds-linux-kernel-master-recompile-it-and-boot-it-wi/49349237#49349237

This builds everything from source, including the toolchain and the image, and ensures that everything is compatible.

Comment: I had to additionally install `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` (without an explicit gcc version)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if you are just experimenting on your PC, it may be ok to use `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc program.c -static`.

This way, there is no need for dynamic linker as the binaries contains everything.