# how to generate ARM64 Ubuntu Server ISO?

Tags: iso

I want to install a Ubuntu Server ISO like http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04.4-server-arm64.iso with a custom kernel.

Are there tools to regenerate ISO with new kernel?

Comment: Does this help?  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cross compile for ARM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250696/how-to-cross-compile-for-arm)  See also: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/ARMKernelCrossCompile

Comment: These options dont help as I cant boot the original Ubuntu distro. These methods allow you to update the kernel after booting once to the original Ubuntu distro.

Comment: You're going to have to use Ubuntu, or some operating system, to dev your own kernel.

Comment: Yes I agree. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 to dev a v5.7 kernel and have built it. I am not sure on how to create a Ubuntu ISO with a v5.7 kernel.