# Raspberri pi ubuntu server preinstalled "ubuntu-image" definition

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi

I am chasing down how the "preinstalled" Raspberry Pi images are being generated. What I found so far:

[ubuntu-image](https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-image) is the tool for generating those images, which requires a *yaml* file with the definition of the image to build. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find the source for the build. In the [models repo](https://github.com/snapcore/models), the preinstalled one is missing.

I just want to be able to pre-bake images so it can be pre-provisioned to the iSCSI servers automatically. It is very interesting that in an opensource world, this particular piece is terribly hidden.

It seems that there are some unit tests that contain files that should be close to what preinstall is doing on "internal/statemachine/testdata/image_definitions/test_raspi.yaml" in the ubuntu-image repository.

There are multiple places where this is being asked such as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350211/how-to-build-preinstalled-ubuntu-server-image?newreg=ef296b7d605c48b7b40388ba83dfb342), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301519/where-are-the-scripts-that-build-prebuilt-images-for-raspberry-pi), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350211/how-to-build-preinstalled-ubuntu-server-image).

Comment: Is https://github.com/snapcore/pi-gadget what you're looking for? https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-image/blob/main/ubuntu-image.rst => "Classic images are built from a local gadget tree path. The gadget tree is nothing more than a primed [gadget snap](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/Gadget-snap)"  => linked wiki page moved to https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/gadget-snaps/696 which links to that repo